# Why my PUT request using the google spreadsheet isn’t working?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I’ve been through every step mentioned here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#changing_contents_of_a_cell using the protocol and submitting the requests, right now, with POSTMAN before doing an actual script.

On the step of editing a cell via PUT i get a **403 Forbidden** with the error "**If-Match or If-None-Match header or entry etag attribute required**”.

Right now my request URL is:

**PUT** https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/MY_SPREADSHEET_ID/od6/private/full/R1C1?v=3.0

**Headers:**
**Authorization** Bearer {my access token}
**Content-Type** application/atom+xml

**Raw**

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:gs="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006">
  <id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/MY_SPREADSHEET_ID/od6/private/full/R1C1</id>
  <link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml"
    href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/MY_SPREADSHIT_ID/od6/private/full/R1C1"/>
  <gs:cell row="1" col="1" inputValue="hello"/>
</entry>
```

Any ideas please?
ps.: if I remove the ?v=3.0 there will be another error demanding the version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the header If-Match:*

It should work out of the box that way, however, more on subject can be found on http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html